# Washing machine in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Here is my problem statement for the washing machine code:

[image: Problem Statement]

I have written the module completely according to the given specifications but I am struck at the 100 clock cycles or 50 clock cycles.

I am not getting any idea of how I can make the code stop there and wait for 100 clock cycles or 50 clock cycles to execute having no effect on the output during clock cycle execution.

```
module Washing_Machine(clk,power,water_full,detergent_full,spin_dry,wash_ongoing,spindry_ongoing,state0,state1);
         input  clk,water_full,detergent_full,spin_dry;
         input  power;
         output reg wash_ongoing,spindry_ongoing;
  output reg state0;
  output reg state1;
            always @ (posedge clk)
            begin
              if(power == 1'b0)
                begin
                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                  //idle state
                  state0         = 1'bx;
                  state1         = 1'bx;
                end
              else if(power == 1'b1)
                begin
                  case ({spin_dry,water_full,detergent_full})
                    3'b000 : begin
                                  //water state and waits for water full.
                                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                                  // water state
                                  state0         = 1'b0;
                                  state1         = 1'b0;
                             end
                    3'b010 : begin
                                  // water state and water full = 1 and 
                                  //goes to detergent state
                                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                                  //detergent state
                                  state0         = 1'b0;
                                  state1         = 1'b1;           
                             end
                    3'b011 : begin
                                  // detergent state and detergent full = 1 and 
                                  //goes to wash state and assigns
                                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b1;
                                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                                  //wash state
                                  state0        = 1'b1;
                                  state1        = 1'b0;
                                  // now it waits for 100 clock cycles.....


                                 **I am struck here**
                                  
                                  
                                  //after
                                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                                  // spin dry state
                                  state0         = 1'b1;
                                  state1         = 1'b1;
                                  //assigns
                                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b1;
                                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                                  // after 50 clock cycles.....




                                  // assigns
                                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                                  // idle state
                                  state0         = 1'bx;
                                  state1         = 1'bx;                         
                             end
                    3'b100 , 3'b101 , 3'b110 , 3'b111 :
                    begin
                          // directly goes to spin dry state
                          // spin dry state
                          state0         = 1'b1;
                          state1         = 1'b1;
                          //assigns
                          spindry_ongoing  = 1'b1;
                          wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                          // after 50 clock cycles....



                          // assigns
                          spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                          // idle state
                          state0         = 1'bx;
                          state1         = 1'bx; 
                    end                    
                  endcase
                end
            end
  endmodule
```

Comment: Maybe you powered off your washing machine after 100 clock cycles? You have to describe your objective, expected results, obtained results; also attach code, and testbench. Otherwise nobody is gonna look at these chunks of code.

Comment: Create an additional state called `wait`. After the washing begin cycle, instead of setting spin cycle start, set the wait state. Inside the wait state, increment a counter. If counter less than 100, set next state as wait. If counter is 100, then set next state as spin cycle. The addition of a wait state with a counter is one way of implementing what you probably need.

Comment: I have edited the question and posted the required specifications. Please check @MituRaj

Comment: This is not how an FSM is described in Verilog. Your code needs major re-work. https://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/verilog_fsm.html

Comment: "x" is not something you would use if implementing in actual hardware.  "x" denotes unknown value.  Normally a state machine is written with the state variable(s) as the selector in the case statement.  The state is changed by outside events.  

Pseudo example:
case (state)
2'b00:  // water state
   if (water_full)  state <= 2'b10;  // change to detergent state.  
2'b10:  // detergent state
etc...

As for waiting for n clock cycles: implement a counter inside the state, and the condition for leaving the state is that the counter reaches your target value.  Sorry for poor formatting.

Comment: Just put a counter in one of your states. If the counter reaches the count you want, move on to the next state. If not, stay in the same state.

Answer (score 1):

OK, to simplify readability of your state machine, I recommend using the state variable (and only that) as the case statement selector.

```
/* State definitions
000 = Idle state
001 = Water state
010 = Detergent state
etc...
*/
reg [2:0] state;

case (state)
// Idle state
3'b000:  begin
  // Set any outputs as desired
  // Wait for "trigger" to move to next state
  if (power == 1) begin
      state    <= 3'b001;  // jump to water state
      water_on <= 1;       // turn on the water valve
  end
end

// Water state
3'b001: begin
  // Set any outputs as desired
  // Wait for "trigger" to move to next state

  your code here
end
```

etc.

With regards to waiting a number of clock cycles:

- implement an incrementing counter in the desired state.
- the condition for exiting the state is when the counter reaches your target value.